# Jackson Deserialize Non-Annotated List

Tags: xml, jackson, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize this xml list

```
<Element name=1>
   <property1>
</Element>
<Element name=2>
   <property1>
</Element>
```

with a custom Deserializer, but when I read this xml with the mapper

```
mapper.readValue(raw,Inventory.class);
```

I always get a json object with the last element instead of getting a json array.

I tried different configuration like this one

```
JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper(module);
```

But nothing has changed.

I would like to keep using my custom deserializer instead of using annotation, because the element is quite complicated and I simplified it to show you the issue.

Comment: `setDefaultUseWrapper` works as advertised. Can you post the code for your custom deserializer ?

Comment: The point is, when I debug my code at the first line of my custom deserializer the json parser has already only one element and not the array.